# How can I know if the app has been opened from a local notification after it has been killed in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am using this callback:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
```

after the app returns from background to find out whether or not a local notification has been used to open it. However, it doesn't get called after the app has been killed in background by the OS. If that's the case, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called but I don't see a trace of the local notification. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate method you can check the `launchOptions` for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`. If the app was launched from a local notification you will be able to access it.

Here's an example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let localNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
        //do your thing here
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Good answer mate.